# How to enable health in Spring Boot Actuator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, health-check

I have to check whether my service / app works or not.

I've added dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
<version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and also tried to add `management.endpoint.health.show-details: always` to `application.yml` but it didn't help.

I tried to go to `http://localhost:8080/actuator/health`, `http://localhost:8080/health` but it returned 404 error.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this code on your application.yaml. This is worked for Spring boot 2.6.7.

```
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health
```

Answer (score 0):

**By default Spring boot enables security for all actuator endpoints**

You can disable that feature using below property

```
management.security.enabled=false
```

Henceforth, try to run the application and hit the endpoint

```
http://localhost:8080/actuator
```

Comment: It didn't help.

Comment: Try removing the version from your dependency and let spring pull it based on your spring boot version and then try !

Comment: It would help if you posted your whole pom.xml and application.properties files.

Answer (score 0):

As you see, you have 404 both on

```
http://localhost:8080/actuator/health
```

and

```
http://localhost:8080/health
```

Reason for this is not because security is enabled, if security was enabled you will get 401 or 403.
You probably need to expose actuator endpoints in `application.yaml` file.

Something like this:

```
management:
 endpoints:
   web:
     exposure:
       include: "health,info"
```

And if you have security enabled, you need to write you own `SecurityFilterChain` implementation in which you will disable security on all Actuator endpoints, or in your case only on those that you exposed in your `application.yaml` file.

Example:

```
   @Configuration
   class ActuatorSecurityAutoConfiguration {

   @Bean
   SecurityFilterChain 
   surpassingActuatorSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity 
   httpSecurity) throws Exception {
     return httpSecurity
            .requestMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint())
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .permitAll()
            .and().build();
     }
   }
```